# Pass cookie in http GET request jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

Ideally, my request should be like this:

```
/oauth2/v1/consent?OCIS_REQ=asdfakdsfjsdfkjdfkjkdf
```

Where "asdfakdsfjsdfkjdfkjkdf" is my Cookie

Im passing it as :

```
/oauth2/v1/consent?${COOKIE_OCIS_REQ}
```

But my `"${COOKIE_OCIS_REQ}"` Variable is not getting replaced with the cookie. 
Though I set the cookie in Header Manager and enabled CookieManager.save.cookies=true in jmeter.properties and passing it in HTTP Header Manager as
Name : `Cookie`    Value :  `${COOKIE_OCIS_REQ}`

The request is simply going like :
GET https://vkon.demo.internal.com:1111/oauth2/v1/consent${COOKIE_OCIS_REQ}

Cookie Data:

asdfakdsfjsdfkjdfkjkdf

Why my Variable is not getting replaced ?? I'm really fed up with this.

I tried passing it a parameter in request, User defined variable Also but no luck!!

Comment: After setting true in jmeter.properties, did you restart the JMeter which is a MUST? and are you sure with cookie variable name as "COOKIE_OCIS_REQ"?

Comment: what does that mean? it worked??

Comment: Thanks!! Naveen . Yes i have restarted Jmeter . Jmeter shows the cookie Cookie Data:
Like:
-ORA_OCIS_CG_ST_tas_tas.demo.oracle.com=sadfdsfadsfadsfads
-OCIS_REQ=asdfakdsfjsdfkjdfkjkdf

The cookie data is not same all the times . it keeps on changing. But thats not big deal .
I'm passing variable as ${COOKIE_OCIS_REQ} in my request "https://vkon.demo.internal.com:1111/oauth2/v1/consent${COOKIE_OCIS_REQ}"

Is the this correct or am i making some mistake ?? please guide

Comment: can you add Debug sampler and View Results Tree and see what is stored in Cookie variables (prefixed with COOKIE). share with us for reference. and also share the response in which COOKIE is sent

Answer (score 0):

First, check what all `Cookie variables` are created by adding `Debug Sampler` and `View Results Tree`.

Then run the test and look at the Debug Sampler result in View Results Tree to check the Cookie variables saved as follows:

[image]

From the above image, it is clear that `COOKIE_NID` is created and can be used in other requests using `${COOKIE_NID}` syntax.

Comment: Thanks Naveen. I was not passing correct Cookie name . I corrected and it worked . Thanks for you kind help.!!

Comment: Please help me with this:How can i extract accessToken form below response and pass it as variable
 <!doctype html><html> <base href="/ui/v1/public/16.4.6-M1.7375/"><!-- build:css css/signin.css --> <link rel="stylesheet" href="legacyModule/css/oj-alta-login.css" type="text/css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="legacyModule/css/signin-template.css" type="text/css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="legacyModule/css/animations.css" type="text/css"/> <!-- endbuild --> <script> var GlobalConfig = { accessToken: 'eyJ4NXQjUzI1NiI6Ill7aA', browserPreferredLocale: 'en-US', isSsoCookiePresent: 'false' };

Comment: add regex extractor as a child of the sampler in which you are getting the above response.  reference http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html. try regex as follows: "accessToken: '(.*?)', " (remove double quotes when you paste it)

Comment: Thanks Naveen i was able to extract using above regex. :)