# Session cookie value is not getting passed to request though it shows in debug sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Unable to get the COOKIE value to request header from Cookie variables though it is getting printed in Debug Sampler.

Followed below links, however unable to resolve my issue:
[Pass cookie in http GET request jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651902/pass-cookie-in-http-get-request-jmeter)

Added CookieManager.save.cookies=true in user.properties file

Restarted JMeter

Added HTTP Cookie Manager

Added Debug Sampler

Cookie variables are printing (COOKIE_JSEID=xxxx) in Debug sampler

In the request header it should go as:

Cookie (header name):JSEID=xxxxx (value)

Hence tried to pass it as JSEID=${COOKIE_JSEID}

Also it prints the value to log if tried with Beanshell Sampler

```
`log.info("COOKIE value is :" + ${COOKIE_JSEID})`
```

However it always going as ${COOKIE_JSEID}, not fetching the cookie value hence request is failing.

Comment: You want to set/add cookie using variable?

Comment: This is session cookie which needs to be used in one of the request's header (if HTTP Cookie Manager is not set, then session ID is not getting generated and all requests will fail, if Added Cookie Manager COOKIE_SID can be seen in Debug Sampler and requests will PASS). In one of the previous projects had used the Cookie value by passing as variable ${COOKIE_SID} and it was successful however this time unable to get the value here. Please guide.